# No puedo definir varias etiquetas <script>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-datepicker

Tengo el siguiente código

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Style/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Style/styleAlert.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 



</head>
<body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
        </script>

        <script src="~/Scripts/jsLogin.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

pero no me permite dejar los dos, me sale un mensaje de error que dice

> 0x800a138a - Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: Se esperaba
>   una función

Ya los he cambiado de orden y he hecho varios cambios pero ninguno a funcionado solo me funciona si coloco solo el:

> script src="~/Scripts/jsLogin.js"> /script>.

O solo cuando coloco

> $(function () {
>                       $("#datepicker").datepicker();
>                   });

Comment: Para que usas ~ al principio de la ruta que pasas al src?

Comment: Muestra tu código completo para tener una idea asm clara de cual puede ser el problema

Comment: Le pongo el  ~ porque esta en una carpeta en la raiz

Comment: no se entiende lo que necesitas

Comment: @SebastianMateusVillegas no tenía ni idea que una virgulilla en la ruta servía para saltar directamente a la carpeta raíz del sitio, no veo el por que te chilla tu código

Comment: En que linea te marca el error?

Comment: No, no, no... para hacer referencia al root sólo tienes que empezar por `/` y ya está: **`<script src="/Scripts/jsLogin.js"></script>`**. Eso sí, asegúrate que tienes un directorio llamado `Scripts`  en el root y que tu archivo `jsLogin.js` está dentro de él. Usar `~` te dará error en la ruta.

Comment: cuando tiene que ejecutar  $(function () { $("#datepicker").datepicker(); });

Answer (score 3):

"~" Solo vale para la consola Linux no para dentro de un HTML !!
Además lleva a la carpeta HOME del usuario, no a la carpeta raiz

Si quieres referirte a un fichero en una ruta usa su ruta ABSOLUTA (toda la ruta)

> /home/sebastian/scripts/JsLogin.js

También puedes usar una ruta RELATIVA que es como si te movieses con el comando 'cd' y se lo tienes que decir...
Ejemplo:
Para la misma carpeta:

> ./JsLogin.js

Para carpeta que esta "detrás" y se llama otrosScript:

> ../otrosScript/otroFichero.js

Comment: Aunque si ese fuera el problema, no mandaría error de ejecución de JS, si no que le diría que no se encontró la ruta, esta solución no necesariamente es para el error de ejecución de JS, a menos que el OP comente que su problema quedó solucionado